# Kmeans as custom layer in functional model

Tags: tensorflow.js

We are planning to use kmeans to split our data and have 10 separate fully connected models to estimate results for each group from kmeans separately.

One obvious way is to have 10 separate tfjs models and separate kmeans on the beginning.

As tfjs supports functional models and custom layers. Alternative is to have kmeans as fist custom layer and then several dense layers connected to it. Is it possible to use existing layer API to receive 20 Tensors, perform kmeans and have 10 different set of 20 Tensors as output to next layers? Do you see any issues with this approach? Is there another alternative?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kmeans is not yet implemented in tfjs. Had it been it couldn't have been considered as a layer itself. You can however create a two stage model in your class by supposing that you yourself you manage to have your own implementation of kmeans.

You'll simply have to pass the result of one model to the other using a conditional statement. The first model -kmeans - will output the class of the data and the second model - one out 10 - is chosen based on the output of the first model.

Having said that, all these can be done in one shot using either the sequential API `tf.sequential` or the functional one `tf.model`. There are kmeans implementation in js that will return js arrays as vectors. These arrays can be converted to tensors whose shape will determine the shape of the layers. Using FCNN , we can have an output for each kmeans class.